# Mysql longtext wont save certain text?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I have a script in my back end that allows me to save default sign up emails. It work with some messages, but some it doesn't. I have the field set to "longtext" and "utf8_general_ci". My current code will save this message:

> Hello this is a default email from your real estate company. If you have received this email, you have signed up for our website. Hello this is a default email from your real estate company. If you have received this email, you have signed up for our website.
>
> If you are looking for Texas "ranch" houses, you have came to the right place.

But will not save this:

> The new "space gray" iPhone 5s will join the silver and gold models when Apple's flagship handset goes on sale next Friday, Sept. 20. Last year, the iPhone 5 was available in white and black.
>
> The change means the iPhone 5s is no longer available in true black, with Apple instead opting to change the aluminum back and sides to a lighter shade of gray. The glass back and front of the device remain black.

I have no idea why it will save certain message, then not save others... Here is my code:

jQuery on admin page:

```
$(function() { 
$( "#defaultemail-ebook-submit" ).click(function() {
    $("#defaultemail-ebook-form").ajaxSubmit({url: 'defaultemails.php', type: 'post', success: alert("Email with ebook has been set!")})
});
});
```

defaultemails.php:

```
$defaultemailebook = $_REQUEST['defaultemail-ebook'];

if (isset($_POST['defaultemail-ebook'])) {
mysql_query("UPDATE default_emails SET email_ebook='". $defaultemailebook ."' WHERE id = '1'");

echo $defaultemailebook;
}
```

Whenever I submit these emails, even the ones that don't submit, I always receive a success alert... Anyone have any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: I guess you must escape the data if it contains special characters like `'` in `apple's`

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the fact that the submitted text can have apostrophe (') characters in.  When your code encounters one, it treats it as the end of the string.

This is not only a problem for the text that is not saved, it's also vulnerable to SQL injection.

You need to handle the string safely, either by changing how you execute the SQL or by trapping single quotes in the text and handling them.

Comment: So could I use strpos() to look for apostrophes, then add a \ before them? Also, are there any other characters that will cause such an error?

Comment: Well if \ is used to escape the apostrophe, then it seems reasonable to assume that \ has some special meaning that also needs to be escaped if it features legitimately in your text, probably by replacing it with \\.

Answer (score 0):

A much more robust solution would be to use an extension like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), with prepared statements. This effectively escapes input for you and is more secure than using functions like addslashes().

For example, in your defaultemails.php script:

```
//make sure the email address is set
if(!isset($_POST['defaultemail-ebook'])) { //it's better to use $_POST over $_REQUEST if you know it's a POST field
    //handle email address not provided
}

$emailAddress = $_POST['defaultemail-ebook'];

//validate the email address
if(!filter_var($emailAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    //handle invalid email address
}

//update the database
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password'); //replace with your details
$sth = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE default_emails SET email_ebook = ? WHERE id = 1;');
$sth->execute(array($emailAddress));

echo $emailAddress;
```